# One hot encoding sentences

Tags: python, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

Here my implementation of one-got encoding :

```
%reset -f

import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

sentences = []
s1 = 'this is sentence 1'
s2 = 'this is sentence 2'

sentences.append(s1)
sentences.append(s2)

def get_all_words(sentences) : 

  unf = [s.split(' ') for s in sentences]

  all_words = []

  for f in unf : 
    for f2 in f : 
      all_words.append(f2)

  return all_words



def get_one_hot(s , s1 , all_words) : 
  flattened = []
  one_hot_encoded_df = pd.get_dummies(list(set(all_words)))
  for a in [np.array(one_hot_encoded_df[s]) for s in s1.split(' ')] : 
    for aa in a : 
      flattened.append(aa)

  return flattened

all_words = get_all_words(sentences)

print(get_one_hot(sentences , s1 , all_words))

print(get_one_hot(sentences , s2 , all_words))
```

this returns :

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

As can see a sparse vector is returns for small sentences. It appears the encoding is occurring at character level instead of word level ? How to correctly on-hot encode below words ?

I think the encodings should be ? :

```
s1 -> 1, 1, 1, 1
s2 -> 1, 1, 1, 0
```

Comment: It isn't doing character encoding, it's just flattening a list a numpy arrays. `[np.array(one_hot_encoded_df[s]) for s in s1.split(' ')]` comes out as `[array([1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8), array([0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=uint8), array([0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8), array([0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=uint8), array([1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)]` and then the subsequent for-loop just takes those individual arrays and appends them into a single array which is how you're getting your current answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Encoding at character level**

This is because of the loop:

```
  for f in unf : 
    for f2 in f : 
      all_words.append(f2)
```

that `f2` is looping over characters of string `f`. Indeed you can rewrite the whole function to be:

```
def get_all_words(sentences) :
  unf = [s.split(' ') for s in sentences]
  return list(set([word for sen in unf for word in sen]))
```

**correct one-hot encoding**

This loop

```
  for a in [np.array(one_hot_encoded_df[s]) for s in s1.split(' ')] : 
    for aa in a : 
      flattened.append(aa)
```

is actually making a very long vector. Let's look at the output of `one_hot_encoded_df = pd.get_dummies(list(set(all_words)))`:

```
   1  2  is  sentence  this
0  0  1   0         0     0
1  0  0   0         0     1
2  1  0   0         0     0
3  0  0   1         0     0
4  0  0   0         1     0
```

the loop above is picking the corresponding columns from this dataframe and append to the output `flattened`. My suggestion will be simply leverage on the pandas feature to allow you to subset a few columns, than sum up, and clip to either 0 or 1, to get the one-hot encoded vector:

```
def get_one_hot(s , s1 , all_words) :
  flattened = []
  one_hot_encoded_df = pd.get_dummies(list(set(all_words)))
  return one_hot_encoded_df[s1.split(' ')].T.sum().clip(0,1).values
```

The output will be:

```
[0 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 0 1 1]
```

For your two sentenses respectively. This is how to interpret these: From the row indices of `one_hot_encoded_df` dataframe, we know that we use 0 for `2`, 1 for `this`, 2 for `1`, etc. So the output `[0 1 1 1 1]` means all items in the bag of words except `2`, which you can confirm with the input `'this is sentence 1'`